# Moving wordpress out of the public directory

Tags: security, hosting, shared-hosting

Is there a way to move wordpress out of the public html directory?

The PHP files responsible for generating html output should be hosted but the php files responsible for database connections and other logic should not be hosted. They can be included by the hosted files in the following way: `../../NotPublic/wp-admin/...`

Symfony does this and actually has only one hosted php. For more explanation as to why this would be a good idea you can check out [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-uG9c3eLp8) video.

I've tried to find instructions on how to do this but cannot find it. Worpress seems to have trouble making a distinction of php files generating output that need to be in the public directory and those that do stuff and should not be able to be requested through the web server (only as includes).

Currently I can use .htaccess to not list the directories or host any of the wp-content directories except wp-content/uploads

Comment: You could create custom routing to do the same thing as Symfony does, however I would argue that the *core level of protection* is the same, if any PHP handles request wrongly, it will get vulnerable regardless of WP/Symfony.
I would focus more on disabling PHP in the uploads folder (most common file upload backdoor) and picking plugins&themes carefuly (OR for only-static site - just put cached output with custom routing somewhere else)

Answer (score 6):

WordPress is very clearly engineered for being placed into web-accessible folder.

While attempt to move it from web folder could be made, it would be very challenging, especially for admin area which uses direct non-routed URLs to PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I always move my default wordpress installation to a folder. this is totally different with installing wordpress *in* a folder. moving default wordpress installation make your site more secure. 
what you have to do is here:

1. go to cpanel > login > file manager > in /public_html or root, create a folder, eg.: "site". it assumes, you now have folder /public_html/site
2. login to your wordpress dashboard > settings > general
3. change "WordPress Address (URL)" to: `http://your-domain-or-whatever.com/`site
4. click  "save changes" button. page will displayed error? no problem.
5. in cpanel file manager, move your wordpress files, to /public_html/site 
   *) what you don't need to move is only : .htaccess, robots.txt, php.ini, and "index.php". remember, do not move "index.php".
6. open and edit "index.php" with code editor. 
   in the last line, you see this code

   ```
   require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
   ```

change it to :

```
 @require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/site/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

remember: "site" can be changed to any folder name you defined in step number 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would that work if you place the wp files out of the public directory (public_html), now it's just a sub directory but still hosted by httpd. The .htaccess can shield some of it but when an admin does something wrong or someone hacks the main config then you won't have the added security that only your templates are hosted and your application is included with `../../notInPublic/myApp/something.php` as with Symfony. It seems that WP doesn't make a distinction between application code and template code (html generating code).

Comment: How is this more secure? Your installation is still inside a public folder.

Comment: I wonder as well @Denis but I guess anything that makes attackers having to think slightly more than the generic wordpress install would make a slight difference. not quite sure what that one would be, but I've seen recommendation that changing the default wp_ table prefix can send people wondering a bit.

Comment: Changing the prefix is pointless since it's an information available in the PHP, it only stops the most basic attacks with hardcoded table names.
For this approach to be at least "security by obscurity" you have to make sure the admin or WP install path is not listed anywhere (in html). Most backdoors are in uploads => disable PHP in the uploads directory and be really picky with themes&plugins or don't use them at all, unless they have development processes to prevent backdoors. Another way is to lock permissions - you have to do all updates manually but it prevents file upload backdoors.